# How to get the value of the hidden field next to the clicked checkbox?

Tags: jquery

I've this two elements next to each other. The **hidden field** contains the ID of the record. When the user check/uncheck the checkbox, I should be able to retrieve the record's **ID**.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckEdit" runat="server" CssClass="ckEditClass" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfEdit" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" />
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$(".ckEditClass").on("click", function () {
    var hidden = $(this).parent().parent().children(":hidden")
    alert(hidden.val());
 })
```

I'm getting `undefined`.

## EDIT

The above code is from Visual Studio. However, when I look at **F12**, I see a `<span>` around the checkbox. Hope this information will help.

```
<td>
    <span class="ckEditClass">
          <asp:CheckBox ID="ckEdit" runat="server" CssClass="ckEditClass" />
    </span>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfEdit" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `closest()` & `find()` methods to do it like following.

```js
$(".ckEditClass:checkbox").on("click", function () {
    var hidden = $(this).closest('td').find(':hidden');
    alert(hidden.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <span class="ckEditClass">
            <input type="checkbox" id="ckEdit" class="ckEditClass"/>
        </span>
        <input type="hidden" id="hfEdit" value="10" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Now, how do I access the checkbox itself as it seems like the `this` represents the `span`, not the wrapped checkbox.

Comment: See the updated answer. Selector changed to `$(".ckEditClass:checkbox")`. @Richard77

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
$(".ckEditClass").on("click", function () {
   var hidden= $(this).next(input[type="hidden"]);
   alert(hidden.val());
});
```

It will check next component of given type and will return it. Then you can alert its value.

Hope it helps